# Scorpion G917 need extra force for right-click

Tags: mouse

I've bought this new mouse, and I'm playing league of legends with it. I find it exhausting pressing right click so many times since I feel like it requires a lot of force to press right click. My old mouse from Red Dragon (S101-BA-1) was much better, since it did not require much force at all to press right click.

Is there any way I can work around this to make it easier to press?

Comment: I'm confused about what answer are you expecting. If the mouse is faulty replace it under warranty and if working as designed get another.

Comment: Maybe someone used it and did some hacky maneuvers to make it work as intended? https://superuser.com/questions/184249/logitech-g500-right-click-needs-extra-force-and-makes-weird-clamping-sound